# Statistic of functions of multiple random variables

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

If there are $n$ independent random variables $x_1,\, x_2,\cdots, x_n$, where $x_i$ follow the p.d.f. $f_i(x_i)$. Now if there is a function $y=f(x_1,\, x_2,\cdots, x_n)$, is there a simple way to find the p.d.f. of random variable $y$.

I know the standard way of doing this is to calculate $P(y\leq y_0)$ and then differentiates it. But given a huge number of $x_i$, this task seems intractable. There is some theorem where we transform $x_1,\, x_2,\cdots, x_n$ to $y_1,\, y_2,\cdots, y_n$ such as theorem 3.9.5 of DeGroot & Schervish's book. Is there any similar result when I am only interested in one function $y=f(x_1,\, x_2,\cdots, x_n)$.

I notice the it is important to make sure the transformation is one-to-one in the similar theorem, which may not be true in a general $y=f(x_1,\, x_2,\cdots, x_n)$. I am not sure whether a general theorem exists.

What about the more specific question below:

If $x_1,\, x_2,\cdots, x_n$ follow uniform distribution on $[0,1/n]$, $y=\sqrt{\sum_i a_i \, x_i^2}$, where $a_i$ is a real constant. Is that possible to find the p.d.f of $y$? What if we can also assume $n\rightarrow \infty$?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately **there is no general method like this**.

The method given in the book you've mentioned is likely the well-known  variable transormation method, however that requires $f$ to be **bijective**, and such, **invertable**. That's also why the dimensionality of the input and output spaces were equal.

The method is the following:

If $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)=(y_1,\dots,y_n)$, with $x := (x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and $y := (y_1,\dots,y_n)$, and $x$ having joint p.d.f. $f_x$ and joint c.d.f. $F_x$, then $\forall i \in \{1,\dots,n\}$:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial a_i}\mathbb{P}(y_1 \le a_1,\dots,y_n \le a_n) = \frac{\partial}{\partial a_i}\mathbb{P}(f(x) \le (a_1,\dots,a_n)) = \\ = \frac{\partial}{\partial a_i}\mathbb{P}(x \le f^{-1}(a_1,\dots,a_n)) = \frac{\partial}{\partial a_i} F_x(f^{-1}(a_1,\dots,a_n)) = \\ = f_x(f^{-1}(a_1,\dots,a_n))\cdot \left(\frac{\partial f^{-1}}{\partial a_i}\right)(a_1,\dots,a_n)$$

where the derivative of the inverse of $f$ is often called the Hessian matrix with elements

$$H_{i,j}(a_1,\dots,a_n) = \left(\left(\frac{\partial f^{-1}}{\partial a_i}\right)(a_1,\dots,a_n)\right)_j$$

So the p.d.f. of $y$ in this case is

$$f_y(a) = f_x(f^{-1}(a))[H_1(a) \cdots H_n(a)]$$

where $H_k(a)$ is the $k$'th row of the Hessian matrix evaluated at $a$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Then, for a simple function like $y=\sqrt{\sum_i a_i x_i^2}$, where $x_i$ are independent variables. Is there any simple way to find the p.d.f of $y$ besides calculating $P(y\leq y_0)$?

Comment: Assume we know all $x_i$ follows uniform distribution. Would this make the question tractable?

Comment: If we know the exact distribution of $x_i$, then yes, that helps a lot! Suddenly, we can write up some integrals and solve them.

Comment: Is calculating $P(y\leq y_0)$ the only way to do this? Or is there a simple way to know the answer?

Comment: I don't think there is a much simpler way than just calculating $\mathbb{P}(y \le y_0)$. The way to calculate the distribution of the sum of random variables is called the "convolution" method, and that simply calculates $\mathbb{P}(y \le y_0)$ for example. But even for two variables, it's a large integral. For $n$ variables, a  really large integral. I encourage you to look up "convolution".

Comment: I learned about convolution method before. But to my memory, that is only applicable for linear combinations of random variables. (Correct me if I am wrong) Anyway, thanks for the comments!

Comment: Yes, it's only for the linear combination part. I'm just saying, that on its own is non-trivial.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the comments, Daniel!